# Power BI - Search for value in column, return True/False

Tags: string, grep, powerbi, dax

I'll describe my question using an oversimplified, hypothetical example.

Let's say I have a text column with a bunch of random words in it. I want to make a new True/False column based on whether or not a word in that row contains the letter A. I can use the following DAX formula:

`ContainsA = IF((SEARCH("A",Table[Words],,0))>=1,TRUE(),FALSE())`

So, if you're here looking for a solution to this problem, this does work. My question is this:

Is there a better way to do this? Surely there must be some DAX function that returns True/False directly, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`CONTAINSSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax) function.

```
ContainsA = CONTAINSSTRING ( Table[Words], "A" )
```